# $\{x\in R, \exists y \in R, xy = yx = 1\}$ forms a group under the ring product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, then I have to prove that the set:

$$\{x\in R, \exists y \in R, xy = yx = 1\}$$

forms a group under the ring product.

I've been able to prove it as its done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709873/proving-that-the-unities-of-a-ring-form-a-group-under-multiplication) but the argument will only work for commutative rings. I'm trying to prove for the general case, but I couldn't.

Comment: The proof works for non-commutative rings as well. Where do you think it might not work?

Comment: @Crostul because of the part $$a \cdot (b \cdot a' \cdot b') = a \cdot (b \cdot b' \cdot a') $$

Comment: Well, the inverse of $ab$ is $b'a'$, not $a'b'$. Note that $$abb'a'=aa'=1$$ and $$b'a'ab=b'b=1$$